# Django: Using .on_delete(SET_NULL) Cascade, how to simultaneously alter other attribute

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cascade

I feel like this should be easy but I cannot seem to find a reference in the docs.

I have a Django Model `Resident` that has a ForeignKey `Property`, when/if a user deletes that `Property` I have set the delete **Cascade** to `SET_NULL` because I feel it is best to not destroy this data as a client could be audited for information about previous residents.

My issue is that there is a **Resident Search** feature to where I have `active` and `inactive` Residents, it works correctly but I noticed a bug today that when a Property is deleted, each associated `Resident` entry still has an **active** attribute set to `true`.  I need to be able to set the `Resident.active` attribute to `false` as well so those residents cannot login to the system anymore, or show up in my **Search Feature** for **active** residents.

How can I do this, other than by manually setting these values when I delete a `Property`?

**Here is the relevant portion of my Model in the event you need it:**

```
class Resident(models.Model):

    property_id = models.ForeignKey('Property', null=True,
                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_column='property_id')

    active = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Comment: Am I correct that different types of properties have incoming FKs/references from different models/tables? And Resident model is one of many models referencing Property model?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes. The relationships are somewhat complex throughout the system

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need this record with no fk? Isn't it more obvious and consistent to have Resident record when one is a resident and not to have such record when one is not?

Comment: If this wasn't a commercial application sure, I could delete history. However, in my instance it is possible that clients will want/need records of every Resident that ever lived at a Property for auditing purposes. I have accomplished what I need by setting the appropriate values for Residents manually when I delete a Property, but I was looking for a "Django" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to override the `delete` method in the `Property` model and change the active field of the related `Resident` there. However this has the same problems as overriding `save`, mainly that this method is not called on bulk deletes or in migrations. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Another option would be to use signals and listen to [pre_delete or post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete)

And a third option would be to check wether the `property_id` is `NULL` instead of using the active field.

Comment: Overriding `delete()` would have been a good option, but my system also uses multiple Databases so I could not pass in the correct `db_alias` to the Model's method

Comment: Why is this not an option? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-to-delete-from

Comment: I am talking about overriding the actual method in the `Property` Model as you actually note in the first part of your answer (it says `save()` in the docs but `delete()` is the same), not using `object.delete(using=db_alias)` in a view on an instance of the ORM.